# How to restrict the same character from being used consecutively?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input

I am trying to create a username input and I want to restrict the user's input onkeypress. The limit of characters that can be entered is 20 + 1 being the fixed prefix.

What I want to achieve is:

1. To restrict user input and accept only A-Z, 0-9, dash (-) and underscore (_). [Solved]
2. To prohibit the user to start their username with dash (-) or underscore (_). [Solved]
3. To prohibit the user to use dash (-) if they have used underscore (_) and the opposite. [Solved]
4. To allow the user to use a max of 3 dashes (-) or 3 underscores (_). [Dashes Solved]
5. To prohibit the user to use consecutive symbols like so (user___ or user--p, etc) [NEED HELP!]

What I can't seem to figure out is how to restrict the underscore (_) to 3 max and how to stop consecutive dashes (-) and underscores (_).

Any help and proper explanation would be greatly appreciated!

My HTML:

```
<form name = "RegForm" method="post" action="index.html" class="login">
    <input type="text" maxlength = "21" name="userID" id="userID"/>
</form>
```

My JavaScript:

```
var userID_textfield = document.forms.RegForm.userID;
userID_textfield.onkeypress = function(e) {

    // Invalid character list
    var prohibited = "!@#$%^&*()+=;:`~\|'?/.><, \"";
    // List of characters that can't be first
    var posRestricted = "-_0123456789";
    // List of characters that can't be used more than once
    var numRestricted = "-_";
    // Get the actual character string value
    var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which);

    /* Goal:
       Validate: Accept only a-z, 0-9, - and _ */  
    if (prohibited.indexOf(key) >= 0) {
        console.log('Invalid key pressed');     
        return false;
    }
    else {
        /* Goals:
           1. Validate: -, _ and 0-9 can't be first
           2. Validate: - and _ can't be last if the userID is 21 characters long */
        if ((posRestricted.indexOf(key) >= 0 && this.value === "@") || (numRestricted.indexOf(key) >= 0 && this.value.length === 20)) {
            console.log("Username can't start with a number, a dash (-) or an underscore (_)");
            return false;
        }
        /* Goals:
           1. Validate: - and _ can't be used more than once each
           2. Validate: if - exists _ can't be used and the opposite' */
        else if (numRestricted.indexOf(key) >= 0) {
            var numResValue = [0, 0];
            for (var a = 0; a < numRestricted.length; a++) {
                for (var b = 0; b < this.value.length; b++) {
                    if (this.value.charAt(b) === numRestricted[a]) {
                       numResValue[a] += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (var c = 0; c <= numResValue.length; c++) {
                if (numResValue[c] < 3) {
                    if (this.value.indexOf(numRestricted.replace(key, "")) === -1) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else {
                     return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    } 
};
```

You can view the code in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ck7f9t6x/3/).

Comment: Is 5. only for - and _? Or all characters?

Comment: It's for "-" and "_". The rest of the characters, except A-Z, 0-9, - and _ are disabled.

Comment: You can do it with regex or you can do by keeping the track of the last character at the string like `s.charAt(s.length-1)` and prohibiting the new one in the eventListener of your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add this : (i updated the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ck7f9t6x/5/)

```
    var lastKey = this.value.charAt(this.value.length-1);
          alert("lastKey = " + lastKey);
          if(lastKey == key){

            return false;
          }
          else{
          var numResValue = [0, 0];
          for (var a = 0; a < numRestricted.length; a++) {
            for (var b = 0; b < this.value.length; b++) {
              if (this.value.charAt(b) === numRestricted[a]) {
                numResValue[a] += 1;
              }
            }
    ...

}
```

Comment: Very nicely done @Asma. No more consecutive dashes and underscores! Only thing off now is the underscore limit. While I have coded them together with the dash not to exceed 3 in number, the underscore doesn't comply while the dash does! Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: actually here var numResValue = [0, 0];  here you have counter for - then _ ,  so instead of a loop on numResValue, you have to test only one of the counters' values (Dash or underscore) as in the JSFiddle updated here : https://jsfiddle.net/ck7f9t6x/6/

Comment: It works! Can you, though, explain what the following line does?
I've not seen such a thing in my life before :p

var indToTest = key === numRestricted[indDash] ? indDash : indUnder;

Comment: this line is like :
if (key === numRestricted[indDash] ) {
   indToTest  = indDash;
} else { 
  indToTest = indUnder; 
}
"?" = if , and ":" = else

Comment: An entire conditional in one line. I'll be using it for sure!

Comment: it's useful when you need to initialize a variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a function for this thing that will accept your string and will return true or false(for valid or not)

```
function checkConsecutive(string){
//break it to array
var a = string.split('');
//check for consecutive
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
if(a[i] == a[i+1]){
return true;
}else{
return false}
}
}
```

I know this is not a perfect solution but it can work.

Comment: and you can call this function on change something.

Comment: Hey @92sharmasaurabh, I have a really tough time trying to understand your code. The way I see it your code is checking the next character of which I type, so it's in fact checking a character that has not yet be typed. I don't see this can work. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: sorry for the trouble dude...plz check http://plnkr.co/edit/veuJdKanCcZSRf2BUmHt?p=preview  this works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/eayfx10f/) JSFiddle

HTML

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="preventConsecutive(this, event)"/>
```

JavaScript

```
function preventConsecutive(el, evt) {
  if(el.value.length > 0) {
    var lastChar = el.value[el.value.length-1];
    if((lastChar === "-" && evt.keyCode === 45) || (lastChar === "_" && evt.keyCode === 95)) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, you can just replace the variable-names in your code.. `el` = `userID_textfield`, `evt` = `e`.. And place it inside your own `onkeypress`-function.

Comment: I did that! That's how I know it works :) One thing I don't understand, though is how this line works:_var lastChar = el.value[el.value.length-1];_
I didn't know you can get the character like that. I though it could only be done using .charAt(). Thanks for letting me know.